# nginx redirecting (not proxying) to the apache backend when a trailing slash is not provided

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, httpd

When I access `http://example.com/folder`, my browser gets a redirect to `example.com:8080`.

However, it works fine when I access `http://example.com/folder/`.

The backend is an `apache` server listening on port `8080`.

`nginx` configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        location / {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect default;
        }
}
```

I've tried:

```
...
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
....
```

Still the same issues. I've looked at similar questions but can't seem to get an answer to this one.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other `location`s which may be taking precedence when called without a trailing slash? P.S. from nginx's POV, if it doesn't end with trailing slash, it's not a folder.

Comment: Nope. Only location.

Comment: Do you actually need the redirect? why not just off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `apache`'s `mod_dir` module was redirecting non-trailing-slash 403s to the URL with the trailing slash.

Here is [documentation on the `mod_dir` `DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

Turning off the directive was a workaround but I like the `DirectorySlash` feature. Just don't want to expose the `apache` backend.

After trying some things, I finally came to a working solution by modifying my `nginx` configuration from this:

```
...
proxy_set_header Host $host;
...
```

...to this:

```
...
proxy_set_header Host $host:80;
...
```

This did the trick! Hope this helps someone cause it really cause me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the `port_in_redirect` option in the configuration.

```
Syntax:     port_in_redirect <on | off>
Default:    on
Context:    http, server, location
```

Directive allows or prevents port indication in redirects handled by Nginx. If `port_in_redirect` is `off`, then Nginx will not add the port in the URL when the request is redirected.

Comment: Think you may have answered the question in my answer before I even asked it. Trying this now.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Looked promising though!

Comment: Ah I see. This worked when there was a reverse-proxy in front of Nginx. Maybe you could try to dump the traffic between Nginx and Apache to see what's going on.